# Easiest way to simply display confirmation that a webservice worked?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I'm calling an asp.net webservice from an ASP clasic page basically just with:

`<a href='http://domain/webservice.asmx/command'>Command</a>`

and when users hit that button it works but they're just shown an xml page. The function will either work or not so I was wondering if it'd be possible to just have a pop up box appear to tell them if it worked or not after they clicked it rather than redirecting them to an xml page.

I'd prefer to not have to use jQuery or another javascript library.

If that's not possible, is there any way to dress up the XML page? Currently it says 'This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.' at the top.

Also, the domain that the webservice is on is different to the domain that the website that's call the webservice is on. Not sure if that matters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [MSDN Link on Calling A WebService From Javascript Using AJAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx).  No JQuery is required and it boils down to having to use the ScriptService attribute on your WebService method and adding a ServiceReference in a ScriptManager control.  You can then easily call your WebService from Javascript and it will call another Javascript function when it finishes.  It is in that response function where you can add your confirmation display.

Answer (score 0):

be aware that this is a bad idea to let the user handle directly - web services are almost always called by your code rather than a client browser session. One reason is that raw error information would be hown to the client if there were a problem.

If you really want to do this, you can either:

- Use AJAX (No framework required - just JS) or
- You can make the webservice non-standard so it returns user-friendly content - perhaps by wrapping it in a website which calls the API behind the scenes and formats the response in a meaningful fashion.

Comment: Thanks, the security isn't an issue as this is an internal site. How can I use ajax to make the call though? All guides have seen require a script manager on the page you're calling from which, afaik, you need to have an asp.net for? I'm calling from an asp classic page.

Comment: Ok, you need to create an `xmlhttprequest` object - google it, it's very common (you can use either a JS version to ge tthe client to make thecall or a server-side version to do it in ASPClassic). I'd suggest the JS version in your model. If you have any problems, let me know and I'll post sample code